# How to measure personalization efforts

Tags: personalization, content-testing

The big question! You can have all the personalization scenarios in the world, at some point you want to know what the hard numbers are. Sitecore gives the opportunity to test components, however A/B testing our personalizations comes with a big issue. Imagine a certain amount of people get to see the non personalized variation (A) while the another number of people see the personalized variation (B). From the second group (B), there are still a number of people who don't get the personalizated version of the component because the rules are not met.

Therefore the question is how can we measure non personalized versus actual personalized content (so the group of people that apply to the personalization rules)? Are there different ways of measuring results in sitecore?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to include 100% of page visitors in your personalization test, you need to make sure the exposure is set to 100%.

[image]

If you're personalizing, you're delivering that personalization through Sitecore components.  Make your first data source of the component the default (non-personalized).  Then add the personalized versions of the content.  Now, 100% of your page visitors will be exposed to the test.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer James! In the meantime I tried wanted to use the Sitecore content testing. So I tried set up a test straight from the experience editor when I added the personalization variations, but the minute I activate and publish the test, the personalization isn't working anymore.